# Postgres time on heroku 5 minutes ahead

Tags: postgresql, heroku, time

It's currently 11:05 UTC. When I call "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" on our Heroku Postgres DB it says 11:10 UTC.

How is that massive difference possible? Do we have to manually set the current time?

Answer (score 0):

current_timestamp function relies on system time and returns time of the beginning of transaction (if any). in your case probably system time is not sync with ntp servers. you can check system time with command 'date'.

Comment: I see your point. But how can it be possible that Heroku is out of sync?? :D

Comment: Computer clocks aren't perfect :)

Comment: Let's see what Heroku tells me. I'll write their answer here

Answer (score 0):

Heroku said the NTP client on this machine stopped working. They've restarted it and it's working again.